# What do you call someone who whines about not getting 100% in an exam?

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone gets a 98% score and complains about it, what do you call them?

Comment: An attention-seeker: drawing attention to how well they really did.

Comment: Do you mean a perfectionist? Or are you implying that it's a "steal brag"?

Comment: Bragging is not what I had in mind, more like a perfectionist but with a pejorative connotation.

Comment: Overachiever ??

Comment: Against whom is their ill-will directed?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, nobody, or perhaps themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would you call a person who focuses only on their faults?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260901/what-would-you-call-a-person-who-focuses-only-on-their-faults)

Comment: Is the idea here that the person complains to the teacher with the aim of getting the grade changed, or merely that the person complains?

Comment: @jsw29 No it's not about complaining to the teacher to get a higher grade, in which case it would be "grade grubber" as Mitch suggested below. It's more like just expressing dissatisfaction when you don't achieve a perfect score.

Comment: How about self-critical?

Answer (score 2):

In American English this kind of person, one who is close to perfect but not quite and seeks those extra points, is called a

> [grade grubber](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grade-grubbing)

They are complaining in order to get those few extra points that, to everyone else, they don't really seem to need. It is a very light pejorative.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can be a grade grubber even with a not so good score of 98%. And your goal is not necessarily 100%, you just want a better grade than your current one and try to convince your teacher about it.

Comment: @Guru Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I would call a person who scores 98% on a test and complains about it a **Type A personality**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_A_and_Type_B_personality_theory):

> Type A and Type B personality hypothesis describes two contrasting personality types. In this hypothesis, personalities that are more competitive, highly organized, ambitious, impatient, highly aware of time management and/or aggressive are labeled Type A, while more relaxed, less 'neurotic', 'frantic', 'explainable', personalities are labeled Type B.

The complaint arises *mostly* from a combination of (1) competitiveness, and (2) ambition with the high degree of organization required to achieve that ambition. While our someone may have scored 98%, members in her "peer group" may have scored higher. From her perspective, not good. Also, the ambition was to score 100%, not 98%. Not good enough.